# Why are there so many religions?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

If one religion is true, why wouldn't everybody would believe it?

As there are multiple religions, does that mean that none of them are correct. Or is my leading statement wrong, and  one or more could be correct?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_%28logic%29

Comment: As the different streams having their sources in different places all mingle their waters in the sea, so, O Lord, the different paths which men take through different tendencies, various though they appear, crooked or straight, all lead to Thee." Mahimnah-stotra.

Comment: Any downvote reasons?

Comment: You're going to have to prove why you think that because something is true, everyone would believe it. Flat-earthers still exist, science is extremely political these days, and not everyone lives in a first world country.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm closing because it's unclear what you are asking. Each question you ask is clear, but you ask 3 distinct questions. "Why are there so many religions" is a history or social psych question, off-topic here. "If one religion is true, why wouldn't everyone believe it?" is too broad without some explanation. What makes you think that such a premise leads to such a conclusion? "... does that mean none of them are correct?" seems to be a question along a similar train of thought, but the reverse. What question are you asking here?

Comment: No, that's fair enough.

Comment: If something is true in the formal sense, then there is no need for belief.

Comment: Why are there so many political ideologies?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to assume that if something is true, everybody would believe it. However, in ancient times, people believed the earth was flat. Now, we believe that the earth is round (like a pancake). Clearly at least one of these two ideas must be wrong. This is in contradiction with your premise that if everything is true, everybody would believe it.

Comment: I mean current day.

Comment: @Tim so, only at this moment you assume that if something is true, everybody would believe it? Why not in ancient times? What's the difference? Before, even the greatest minds of the world thought the earth was flat. It's rather arrogant to say there's not even the slightest possibility that the great minds of today aren't wrong on some small details, no?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is, with all the current knowledge, why isn't religion agreed upon?

Comment: @Tim isn't it obvious? There's an element of faith.